# Spring boot doesn't wait for request

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Yesterday I got very strange spring boot behaviour

For example: i'm trying to start server using `./gradlew bootRun`:

```
... 
:findMainClass
:bootRun

 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)

2016-01-19 16:37:15.315  INFO 6118 --- [           main] c.e.server.Application$Companion         : Starting Application.Companion on fake with PID 6118 (/home/user/code/xproject/server/build/classes/main started by user in /home/user/code/xproject/server)
2016-01-19 16:37:15.320  INFO 6118 --- [           main] c.e.server.Application$Companion         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-01-19 16:37:15.400  INFO 6118 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@a3ec6b: startup date [Tue Jan 19 16:37:15 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-19 16:37:17.908  INFO 6118 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-01-19 16:37:17.923  INFO 6118 --- [           main] c.e.server.Application$Companion         : Started Application.Companion in 3.048 seconds (JVM running for 3.421)
2016-01-19 16:37:17.924  INFO 6118 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@a3ec6b: startup date [Tue Jan 19 16:37:15 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-19 16:37:17.930  INFO 6118 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 23.756 secs
```

So it doesn't wait for requests as it always did. I thought there are some problems with classpath, so I put few annotated methods as @PostConstruct in Controllers and Services and can confirm that they are called and all dependencies are injected at that point.

Here is my gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-beta-4584' 
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

jar {
    baseName = 'xproject'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.8.2.RELEASE'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.restfb:restfb:1.18.1"

    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs += ['java', 'kotlin']
    }

    test {
        java.srcDirs += 'test'
    }
}
```

**UPD#1**

Here is Application class(I haven't touch it from the beginning).

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class Application {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD#2**

Small self-contained code

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class GreetingController {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreetingController.class, a);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("!! Post construct called");
    }

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Gives me almost the same result

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)

2016-01-19 17:18:19.790  INFO 8230 --- [  restartedMain] hello.GreetingController                 : Starting GreetingController on fake with PID 8230 (/home/user/code/xproject/server/build/classes/main started by user in /home/user/code/xproject/server)
2016-01-19 17:18:19.814  INFO 8230 --- [  restartedMain] hello.GreetingController                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-01-19 17:18:19.918  INFO 8230 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@71ceb8: startup date [Tue Jan 19 17:18:19 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
!! Post construct called
2016-01-19 17:18:22.860  INFO 8230 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2016-01-19 17:18:22.905  INFO 8230 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-01-19 17:18:22.922  INFO 8230 --- [  restartedMain] hello.GreetingController                 : Started GreetingController in 4.022 seconds (JVM running for 4.949)
2016-01-19 17:18:22.924  INFO 8230 --- [       Thread-8] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@71ceb8: startup date [Tue Jan 19 17:18:19 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-19 17:18:22.930  INFO 8230 --- [       Thread-8] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please show your "Application" or "Application.Companion" class.

Comment: @dunni i've updated question

Comment: Your path is borked somehow, it doesn't detect tomcat and as such doesn't start a web application, without that it ends immediately. (It should start an Web content and not a plain context. Make sure that there isn't anything turning the web stuff of.

Comment: @M.Deinum I really don't know how to check that. I see that java is started with tons of libraries specified in classpath. I've tried different versions of gradle as well - no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having exactly the same issue you just described and in my case, I had forgotten to add spring-boot-starter-web as dependency. I had copy/pasted the dependencies from a basic example just having spring-boot-starter and I misread it.
Once I added it, the container was started normally and I got a regular web app listening at the 8080 port.

It is my first very basic test so it just has spring-boot-starter-web, kotlin-stdlib and kotlin-reflect as dependencies and class that looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application::class.java)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```

From what I see in your code, the only thing I can think of is that you might require kotlin-reflect as well. I got the idea of including it from this [blog post](https://moelholm.com/2017/03/12/spring-boot-hello-world-kotlin/) and [this sample project](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-boot-kotlin-demo) also uses it so...
Good luck!